# How do I implement thumbnail effect in image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I want to achieve the thumbnail effect in Image, The thumbnail effect achieved by applying it into div like

```
<div class="fui-container fui-image-thumb">
  <a href="#">      
    <span>Dhabri Kunda; This picture is for Dhabri Kunda</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can see this in [codepen](http://codepen.io/tanmoy911/pen/PNVMEe)

Now I want this effect into `img` tag directly like

```
<img class="fui-Morph" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dpUhA-kOBgs/UBEE0NyP_yI/AAAAAAAAAEE/_Q3hGLXkotQ/s640/Dhabri+Kunda.jpg" style="width:30%" alt="portrait">
  <h4>Image Morph on Hover</h4>
```

What I have tried:

When I replace tag into `<img>` tag it does not worked. Rather I failed to find the problem. When I change the tag into `<img>` tag I also delete the
url portion from `.fui-image-thumb` a section.

Please help I am failed to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Link is broken. Please update.

Comment: The "box" effect is done with **background** images not inline images...

Comment: Is this even possible to implement in inline images